# Compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^T \exp(x x^T) x )$

Tags: matrix-calculus

How to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big(x^T \exp{x x^T} x \big), ~x \in \mathbb{R^n}$?

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and define a new (symmetric) matrix variable 
$$M=xx^T$$
We'll also need a general result about the differential of the trace of a function
$$d\,{\rm tr}(f(X))=f'(X^T):dX$$
where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$.

Write the function in terms of this new variable and find its differential and then its gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= {\rm tr}\big(M\exp(M)\big) \cr\cr
df &= (I+M)\exp(M):dM \cr
  &= (I+M)\exp(M):(dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T) \cr
  &= 2\,(I+M)\exp(M):dx\,x^T \cr
  &= 2\,(I+M)\exp(M)x:dx \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,(I+xx^T)\exp(xx^T)x \cr\cr
}$$